# Invoking begin and end via using-directive?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, using-directives, argument-dependent-lookup

The established idiom for invoking `swap` is:

```
using std::swap
swap(foo, bar);
```

This way, `swap` can be overloaded for user-defined types outside of the `std` namespace.

Should we invoke `begin` and `end` in the same fashion?

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
some_algorithm(begin(some_container), end(some_container));
```

Or should we just write:

```
some_algorithm(std::begin(some_container), std::end(some_container));
```

Comment: sorry, I think this is a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/17562943/819272

Comment: Who decides what the established idioms are?

Comment: @NeilKirk Books like Effective C++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a `using`-*declaration* like that is the correct way IMO. It's also what the standard does with the range for loop: if there is no `begin` or `end` members present then it will call `begin(x)` and `end(x)` with `std` as an associated namespace (i.e. it will find `std::begin` and `std::end` if ADL doesn't find non-member `begin` and `end`).

If you find that writing `using std::begin; using std::end;` all the time is tedious then you can use the `adl_begin` and `adl_end` functions below:

```
namespace aux {

using std::begin;
using std::end;

template<class T>
auto adl_begin(T&& x) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<T>(x)));

template<class T>
auto adl_end(T&& x) -> decltype(end(std::forward<T>(x)));

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_array()
{
    using type = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
    return std::is_array<type>::value;
}

} // namespace aux

template<class T,
         class = typename std::enable_if<!aux::is_array<T>()>::type>
auto adl_begin(T&& x) -> decltype(aux::adl_begin(std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    using std::begin;
    return begin(std::forward<T>(x));
}

template<class T,
         class = typename std::enable_if<!aux::is_array<T>()>::type>
auto adl_end(T&& x) -> decltype(aux::adl_end(std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    using std::end;
    return end(std::forward<T>(x));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T* adl_begin(T (&x)[N])
{
    return std::begin(x);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T* adl_end(T (&x)[N])
{
    return std::end(x);
}
```

This code is pretty monstrous. Hopefully with C++14 this can become less arcane:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Not_array()
{
    using type = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
    return !std::is_array<type>::value;
}

decltype(auto) adl_begin(Not_array&& x)
{
    using std::begin;
    return begin(std::forward<Not_array>(x));
}

decltype(auto) adl_end(Not_array&& x)
{
    using std::end;
    return end(std::forward<Not_array>(x));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T* adl_begin(T (&x)[N])
{
    return std::begin(x);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T* adl_end(T (&x)[N])
{
    return std::end(x);
}
```

Comment: @Useless What you'd expect: it returns the type returned by `begin(T)`. The using-declarations that bring `std::begin` and `std::end` into scope only kick in if ADL doesn't find non-member `begin` or `end`.

Comment: How is this better than writing 1 more character for std::begin?

Comment: @NeilKirk because `std::begin` will do the wrong thing sometimes.

Comment: They should fix the language. This is what puts people off C++.

Comment: @NeilKirk I agree it should be fixed in some way (I got tripped up by two edge cases writing this). Hopefully with C++14 concepts it becomes easier to deal with (solution at end).

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer:* For the pedantic types (or pedants, if you want to be pedantic...), I generally refer to the word *"overload"* here as *"Create functions that have the names `begin` and `end` and do `using std::begin; using std::end;`."*, which, believe me, is not tedious for me to write at all, but is very hard to read and is redundant to read. `:p.`

---

I'll basically give you the possible use-cases of such technique, and later my conclusion.

#### Case 1 - Your `begin` and `end` methods do not act like those of the standard containers

One situation where you may need to overload the `std::begin` and `std::end` functions is when you're using the `begin` and `end` methods of your type in a different way other than to provide iterator-like access to the elements of an object, and want to have overloads of `std::begin` and `std::end` call the begin and end methods used for iteration.

```
struct weird_container {
   void begin() { std::cout << "Start annoying user." }
   void end() { std::cout << "Stop annoying user." }

   iterator iter_begin() { /* return begin iterator */ }
   iterator iter_end() { /* return end iterator */ }
};


auto begin(weird_container& c) {
   return c.iter_begin();
}

auto end(weird_container& c) {
   return c.iter_end();
}
```

However, you wouldn't and shouldn't do such a crazy thing as range-for would break if used with an object of `weird_container`, as per rules of range-for, the `weird_container::begin()` and `weird_container::end()` methods would be found before the stand-alone function variants.

This case therefore brings an argument not to use what you have proposed, as it would break one very useful feature of the language.

#### Case 2 - `begin` and `end` methods aren't defined at all

Another case is when you don't define the `begin` and `end` methods. This is a more common and applicable case, when you want to extend your type to be iteratable without modifying the class interface.

```
struct good_ol_type {
   ...
   some_container& get_data();
   ...
};

auto begin(good_ol_type& x) {
   return x.get_data().begin();
}

auto end(good_ol_type& x) {
   return x.get_data().end();
}
```

This would enable you to use some nifty features on `good_ol_type` (algorithms, range-for, etc) without actually modifying its interface! This is in line with Herb Sutter's recommendation of extending the functionality of types through non-member non-friend functions.

This is the good case, the one where you actually want to overload `std:;begin` and `std::end`.

#### Conclusion

As I haven't *ever* seen someone do something like that of the first case (except for my example), then you'd really want to use what you've proposed and overload `std::begin` and `std::end` wherever applicable.

---

I did not include here the case where you defined both `begin` and `end` methods, and `begin` and `end` functions that does different things than the methods. I believe such a situation is contrived, ill-formed and/or done by a programmer who haven't had much experience delving into the debugger or reading novel template errors.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say but overloading is the wrong terminology here. You can't overload functions in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Simple Thanks for pointing that out. I'll be sure to clear that up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If your some_container is standard container, std:: prefix is needless

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){ 
       std::vector<int>v { 1, 7, 1, 3, 6, 7 };
       std::sort( begin(v), end(v) ); // here ADL search finds std::begin, std::end
}
```

Comment: Even the `std::` prefix on `sort` is needless. But all that holds IF it's a standard container. The question here is about the general case, where the container might or might not be a standard one. In particular, you can't assume that the container must be from `::std::` or `::` (global namespace), it may come from anywhere.

Comment: @MSalters actually the `std::sort` *is* neccessary because `std::vector::iterator` could be a pointer or a type in a nested namespace, in which case ADL will not find `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) of `swap` specifies that the idiom you refer to is common practice in the stl library

> Many components of the standard library (within std) call swap in an
>   unqualified manner to allow custom overloads for non-fundamental types
>   to be called instead of this generic version: Custom overloads of swap
>   declared in the same namespace as the type for which they are provided
>   get selected through argument-dependent lookup over this generic
>   version.

No such thing is present in the documentation for `begin` and `end`.

For this reason, you can definitely use the

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
some_algorithm(begin(some_container), end(some_container));
```

calling convention, but you must be aware that this is a convention which doesn't apply to e.g. standard algorithms but to your code only.

Comment: "cplusplus.com" is an assumption

Comment: @msalters beg you pardon?!

Comment: @StefanoFalasca the reference site you use is known to be full of errors. Prefer to use the latest draft Standard, or at the very least en.cpp.reference.com

Comment: @TemplateRex I assume you are right, and thank you very much for making me aware of this! didn't know.