# How to use begin() free function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, generic-programming

I am currently writing a function template that deals with a generic container. I want to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, because of the reasons mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593086/why-use-non-member-begin-and-end-functions-in-c11). My question is, whether should I use:

```
std::begin( myContainer )
```

Or:

```
using namespace std; // Better use: "using std::begin"
begin( myContainer )
```

Or, in other words, is it okay to overload `begin()` within the `std` namespace? Should I allow users of my function to overload the `begin()` function *in the global namespace* somewhere else as well? How does the STL deal with it?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18780324/1619294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a `using` directive, so let's assume the second snippet contains a `using` declaration instead.

```
using std::begin;
```

If you're creating your own container to go with this function template, provide `Container::begin()` and `Container::end()` member functions, and then it doesn't make a difference whether you use the first or the second. `std::begin()` and `std::end()` will call the respective member functions when available (*§24.7 [iterator.range]*).

On the other hand, if you're creating a function template that should work with any container, those present in the standard library, or a custom container; I'd recommend the second approach.

```
using std::begin;
begin( myContainer );
```

Note that that will enable [ADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) to find user defined overloads for free functions `begin()` and `end()` *within the same namespace as the container definition*. The overloads should not be added to namespace `std` or the global namespace (unless the container definition is also in the global namespace). In the absence of these free function overloads, `std::begin` will be called (because of the `using declaration`) and this in turn will call `Container::begin()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to recommend `using std::begin;` rather than `using namespace std;`? The latter may bring a lot of unwelcome names into the scope.

Comment: @jogojapan Wow, I must've read those lines 3-4 times, and read it as `using std::begin;` every single time, and then copy pasted it as is without catching it yet again! Guess it was a case of the mind seeing what it wanted to see. Thanks for mentioning that; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not okay to overload something in `std` namespace, only specializations are allowed. If you want to enable `ADL` you can use

```
using std::begin;
begin(myContainer)
```

Answer (score 4):

For a custom container, [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) actually can call `begin` in your container. So if you have `MyContainerClass::begin` that will be enough. Same with `std::end` and the constant-iterator versions `std::cbegin` and `std::cend`.