# what is the preferred way to expose custom STL-style iteration?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

(also see [Is there a good way not to hand-write all twelve required Container functions for a custom type in C++?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329813/is-there-a-good-way-not-to-hand-write-all-twelve-required-container-functions-fo) )

---

For a class such as

```
namespace JDanielSmith {
class C
{
    const size_t _size;
    const std::unique_ptr<int[]> _data;

public:
    C(size_t size) : _size(size), _data(new int[size]) {}

    inline const int* get() const noexcept { return _data.get(); }
    inline int* get() noexcept { return _data.get(); }

    size_t size() const noexcept { return _size; }
};
}
```

what is the preferred way to expose iteration?  Should I write `begin()`/`end()` (and `cbegin()`/`cend()`) member functions?

```
const int* cbegin() const {
    return get();
}
const int* cend() const {
    return cbegin() + size();
}
```

or should these be non-member functions?

```
const int* cbegin(const C& c) {
    return c.get();
}
const int* cend(const C& c) {
    return cbegin(c) + c.size();
}
```

Should `begin()`/`end()` have both `const` and non-`const` overloads?

```
    const int* begin() const {
        return get();
    }
    int* begin() {
        return get();
    }
```

Are there any other things to consider?  Are there tools/techniques to make this "easy to get right" and reduce the amount of boiler-plate code?

---

Some related questions/discussion include:

- [Should custom containers have free begin/end functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562943/should-custom-containers-have-free-begin-end-functions)
- [Why use non-member begin and end functions in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593086/why-use-non-member-begin-and-end-functions-in-c11)
- [When to use `std::begin` and `std::end` instead of container specific versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452130/when-to-use-stdbegin-and-stdend-instead-of-container-specific-versions)

Comment: There should be both; members as well as free (or consider if `std::begin` and `std::end` pairs for your case or not before adding *free* versions). Also, you should also have `begin()` and `end()` pairs. And also, member types, `iterator` and `const_iterator` instead of `const int*` or so.

Comment: @SteveJessop: No. I didn't *mean* that at all. I said in the general sense: if `std::begin` doesn't work for you, then you should add yours, in the same namespace, so that ADL should work.

Comment: @Dan: For the code you have posted, you dont have to write the *free* versions, because `std::begin` family would work just fine.

Comment: Related: [Should custom containers have free begin/end functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17562943/819272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating both sets of functions -- member functions as well as non-member functions -- to allow for maximum flexibility.

```
namespace JDanielSmith {
   class C
   {
      const size_t _size;
      const std::unique_ptr<int[]> _data;

      public:
      C(size_t size) : _size(size), _data(new int[size]) {}

      inline const int* get() const { return _data.get(); }
      inline int* get() { return _data.get(); }

      size_t size() const { return _size; }

      int* begin() { return get(); }
      int* end() { return get() + _size; }
      const int* begin() const { return get(); }
      const int* end() const { return get() + _size; }
      const int* cbegin() const { return get(); }
      const int* cend() const { return get() + _size; }

   };

   int* begin(C& c) { return c.begin(); }
   int* end(C& c) { return c.end(); }
   const int* begin(C const& c) { return c.begin(); }
   const int* end(C const& c) { return c.end(); }
   const int* cbegin(C const& c) { return c.begin(); }
   const int* cend(C const& c) { return c.end(); }
}
```

The member functions are necessary if you want to be able to use objects of type `C` as arguments to `std::begin`, `std::end`, `std::cbegin`, and `std::cend`.

The non-member functions are necessary if you want to be able to use objects of type `C` as arguments to just `begin`, `end`, `cbegin`, and `cend`. ADL will make sure that the non-member functions will be found for such usages.

```
int main()
{
   JDanielSmith::C c1(10);

   {
      // Non-const member functions are found
      auto b = std::begin(c1);
      auto e = std::end(c1);
      for (int i = 0; b != e; ++b, ++i )
      {
         *b = i*10;
      }
   }

   JDanielSmith::C const& c2 = c1;
   {
      // Const member functions are found
      auto b = std::begin(c2);
      auto e = std::end(c2);
      for ( ; b != e; ++b )
      {
         std::cout << *b << std::endl;
      }
   }

   {
      // Non-member functions with const-objects as argument are found
      auto b = begin(c2);
      auto e = end(c2);
      for ( ; b != e; ++b )
      {
         std::cout << *b << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why is everyone implementing their own non-member `begin` and `end` functions?  Why don't `std::begin` and `std::end` suffice?

Comment: @Dan, it is a lot of boiler-plate code. The cost of creating such boiler-plate code is very small compared to the benefits.

Comment: @Dan, if you have a need to create many such containers, you might be able to use macros to reduce the amount of hand-typed code. I would use macros if I have more than two containers.

Comment: @BrianFairservice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593086/why-use-non-member-begin-and-end-functions-in-c11

Comment: "The non-member functions are necessary if you want to be able to use objects of type C as arguments to just begin, end, cbegin, and cend" No you don't, the default `std::begin` will already call the member version. You only need to write the non member versions if you literally cannot add member versions, like with arrays or 3rd parties.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I agree that you don't need the non-member functions if you use `std::begin`. You need them for ADL if you use just `begin`.

Comment: @RSahu: Why? Wont unqualified `begin` fall back on `std::begin`, which then calls the member functions?

Comment: @MooingDuck, no. I verified that when I was formulating the answer.

Comment: @Guvante: Top answer says the only advantage is "Free-functions... they can be added afterwards, on a data-structure you cannot alter." which doesn't apply here

Comment: @MooingDuck, remove `using std::begin;`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Templated functions can use the free functions as a simpler way to handle different data types is the point. So if you have generic code to walk a collection it works for `std::vector<int>`, `int[]` and your custom type `T` with free function `begin(T)`, `end(T)`.

Comment: RSahu: That's the normally recommended way to do things, I don't see a reason to remove it. @Guvante: I know the benefits of a global begin, I just don't see the benefits of a _custom_ global begin. The default looks like it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

There is a standard which describes what your class interfaces should look like if you want them to be congruent with the STL.  C++ has this notion of 'concepts' which pin down the requirements for a given class to be a sufficient implementation of a concept.  This almost became a language feature in c++11.

A concept you may be interested in is the [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept.  As you can see, in order to meet the requirements of the Container concept, you need `begin`, `cbegin`, `end`, and `cend` as member functions (among other things).

Since it looks like you're storing your data in an array, you might also be interested in [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer).

Comment: Container has some things in it that this class currently doesn't, the big one being copying. Alternatives would be: satisfy the requirements of Boost.Range, which is "something you can iterate and hence use algorithms on"; or just do enough that range-based for loops work.

Comment: Well. Raw arrays aren't Containers. They're "congruent" with everything in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @Dan Another way of doing that is to make `C` a template which allows you to specify the way the data is stored.  This way you can keep the class interface as member functions which is more conventional (perhaps that's just my opinion).  You can use `std::begin` with `C` if you need a `begin` that isn't a member assuming `C::begin` is reasonable.

Comment: @Dan Well, I would point back to my original answer about the Container concept and Steve Jessop's comment about the Boost.Range concept (which is more minimal and directly what you're asking about).  This is what is required for conventional iteration.

Comment: Note that they had to change their definition/prerequisite of Container to include new container as `std::array`...

Answer (score 2):

I'll take option C.

The main problem here is that `std::begin()` doesn't actually work for finding non-member `begin()` with ADL. So the *real* solution is to write your own that does:

```
namespace details {
    using std::begin;

    template <class C>
    constexpr auto adl_begin(C& c) noexcept(noexcept(begin(c)))
        -> decltype(begin(c))
    {
        return begin(c);
    }
}

using details::adl_begin;
```

Now, it doesn't matter if you write your `begin()` as a member or non-member function, just use `adl_begin(x)` everywhere and it'll just work. As well as for both the standard containers and raw arrays. This conveniently side-steps the member vs. non-member discussion.

---

And yes, you should have `const` and non-`const` overloads of `begin()` and friends, if you want to expose `const` and non-`const` access.

Comment: @Dan Would you rather remember to have to litter your code with `using std::begin; using std::end;`?

Comment: You also need to make that `constexpr` and `noexcept` ;-)

Comment: So why not just implement a member begin and use `std::begin` everywhere?

Comment: @MikeMB Because that won't work on types that have a non-member `begin()`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562943/should-custom-containers-have-free-begin-end-functions

Comment: @TemplateRex It's weird to list `adl_begin()` as being less terse than `begin()` as a con, when being able to write `begin()` requires also writing `using std::begin;` which is net more characters?

Comment: @TemplateRex Also definitely don't understand the pollute namespace with `std::begin` comment.

Comment: I think that was because pre-C++14 auto return, you needed to write `using std::begin` at namespace scope in order for `->decltype(begin(bla)))` to work, a header including `adl_begin` would pollute the namespace

Comment: @TemplateRex Not the global namespace. In my example, I'm polluting `details`, not `::`

Comment: @Barry I see, well, the Q&A is community wiki, so feel free to edit.

Comment: @Barry: "*Because that won't work on types that have a non-member begin().*" But you're *writing* the container. Your container can have member `begin` if you want it to. I can understand adding non-member specializations to `std::begin/end` for a container you don't control. But if its your container, I see nothing to be gained from going the non-standard route of using member functions.

Answer (score -2):

In order to create a valid iterator, you must ensure that std::iterator_traits is valid. This means you must set the iterator category among other things.

An iterator should implement iterator(), iterator(iterator&&), iterator(iterator const&), operator==, operator !=, operator++, operator++(int), operator*, operator=, and operator->. It's also a good idea to add operator< and operator+ if you can (you can't always, e.g. linked lists.)

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:

  using value_type = T;
  class iterator 
  { 
  public:
    using value_type = foo::value_type;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    // or whatever type of iterator you have...
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    // ... 
  };

  class const_iterator 
  {
    // ... 
  };

  iterator begin() { /*...*/ }
  iterator end() { /*...*/ }

  const_iterator cbegin() const { /*...*/ }
  const_iterator cend() const { /*...*/ }

  /* ... */
};
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits for more information on what you need to make a valid iterator. (Note: You also need certain properties to be a valid "container", like .size())

Ideally you should use member functions for begin and end, but it's not required... you can also overload std::begin and std::end. If you don't know how to do that, I suggest you use member functions.

You should create begin() const and end() const, but it should be an alias for cbegin(), NEVER the same as begin()!